# The parallax animation delays when the image is scrolled into position

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, parallax

I have 3 images that have a parallax animated effect. The problem is that the parallax effect has some delay*

*as @[Roko C. Buljan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383904/roko-c-buljan) pointed out, correctly.

How to fix?

Here's my code - the effect is only visible under 670px (as can be seen without putting on the full screen mode, here.)

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const parallaxContainer = document.querySelector(".parallax-container");
  const windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
  let isScrolling = false; // Flag to track scrolling activity
  let isScrollingStopped = false; // Flag to track when scrolling has stopped

  // Define the Intersection Observer options
  const observerOptions = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: "0px",
    threshold: 1 // Trigger when the entire image is not in the viewport
  };

  // Create the Intersection Observer
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      const image = entry.target;
      if (windowWidth < 670) {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          // Image is in viewport, remove grayscale filter
          image.style.filter = "grayscale(0)";
          // Pause the parallax animation by removing the animation CSS property
          image.style.animation = "none";
        } else {
          // Image is not in viewport, apply grayscale filter
          image.style.filter = "grayscale(1)";
          // Resume the parallax animation by restoring the animation CSS property
          image.style.animation = "";
        }
      }
    });
  }, observerOptions);

  // Get all the parallax images and observe each one
  const parallaxImages = document.querySelectorAll(".parallax-image");

  parallaxImages.forEach((item) => {
    observer.observe(item);
  });

  // Function to update the parallax effect
  function updateParallax() {
    const scrollPosition = parallaxContainer.scrollLeft;

    // Apply the parallax effect to each item with a background image
    parallaxImages.forEach((item) => {
      const coefficient = parseFloat(item.dataset.parallaxCoefficient) || 1.0;
      const xOffset = -scrollPosition * coefficient;
      item.style.backgroundPositionX = `${xOffset}px`;
    });

    // Continue updating the parallax effect while scrolling
    if (isScrolling && !isScrollingStopped) {
      requestAnimationFrame(updateParallax);
    }
  }

  // Function to handle scrolling end
  function handleScrollEnd() {
    isScrollingStopped = true;
  }

  // Start the parallax effect when scrolling begins
  parallaxContainer.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    isScrollingStopped = false;
    // Set the flag to true when scrolling starts
    if (!isScrolling) {
      isScrolling = true;
      // Request the first frame of the parallax animation
      requestAnimationFrame(updateParallax);
    }

    // Clear the flag after a short delay (adjust the delay time as needed)
    clearTimeout(parallaxContainer.dataScrollTimer);
    parallaxContainer.dataScrollTimer = setTimeout(function() {
      isScrolling = false;
      handleScrollEnd(); // Call the function to handle scrolling end
    }, 100); // Adjust the delay (in milliseconds) to control the duration of parallax after scroll ends
  });
});
```

```css
.what-we-do {
  padding: 88px 60px 40px 60px;
}


.what-we-do .upper-div h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

.what-we-do h2 {
  font-family: "lato";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 48px;
}

.what-we-do-container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.pics-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 8px;
  height: 576px;
  overflow: hidden;
}



.pics-div p {
  font-family: Lato;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 28px;
  letter-spacing: 0em;
  text-align: left;
}

.pic1,
.pic2,
.pic3 {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pic1 {
  filter: grayscale(1);
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200/300);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 32px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: white;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

.pic2 {
  filter: grayscale(1);
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200/300);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 32px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: white;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

.pic3 {
  filter: grayscale(1);
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200/300);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 32px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: white;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

.pic-upper-text {
  display: flex;
  gap: 32px;
  align-items: center;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  position: relative;
}

.pic1:hover {
  width: 50%;
  filter: grayscale(0);
  transition-duration: 1s;
  .pic-upper-text {
    gap: 150px;
  }
}

.pic2:hover {
  width: 50%;
  filter: grayscale(0);
  transition-duration: 1s;
  .pic-upper-text {
    gap: 150px;
  }
}

.pic3:hover {
  width: 50%;
  filter: grayscale(0);
  transition-duration: 1s;
  .pic-upper-text {
    gap: 150px;
  }
}

section {
  display: block;
}

.what-we-do-container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: auto;
}

.what-we-do-container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.pics-div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  margin-bottom: 74px;
}

.pics-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 8px;
  height: 576px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.parallax-container {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}

.parallax-image {
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  flex: auto;
}

.pic1:hover,
.pic2:hover,
.pic3:hover {
  width: 50%;
  filter: grayscale(0);
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="what-we-do">
  <div class="what-we-do-container">
    <div class="upper-div">
      <h2>Main title</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="pics-div parallax-container">
      <div ontouchstart="changeBullet1()" onclick="window.location.href = 'lorem-ipsum';" class="pic1 parallax-image" data-parallax-coefficient="0.2">
        <div class="pic-upper-text">
          <h3>Title1</h3>
          <svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M8.33398 20H31.6673" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
            <path d="M20 8.33325L31.6667 19.9999L20 31.6666" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum
        </p>
      </div>
      <div ontouchstart="changeBullet2()" onclick="window.location.href = 'lorem-ipsum';" class="pic2 parallax-image" data-parallax-coefficient="0.2">
        <div class="pic-upper-text">
          <h3>Title 2</h3>
          <svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M8.33398 20H31.6673" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
            <path d="M20 8.33325L31.6667 19.9999L20 31.6666" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet
        </p>
      </div>
      <div ontouchstart="changeBullet3()" onclick="window.location.href = 'lorem-ipsum';" class="pic3 parallax-image" data-parallax-coefficient="0.2">
        <div class="pic-upper-text">
          <h3>Title 3</h3>
          <svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M8.33398 20H31.6673" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
            <path d="M20 8.33325L31.6667 19.9999L20 31.6666" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
            </svg>
        </div>

        <p>
          Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bullet-container">
      <div class="bullet-box">
        <div id="bullet1" class="bullet"></div>
        <div id="bullet2" class="bullet"></div>
        <div id="bullet3" class="bullet"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Here it can be seen live: [I removed the link for privacy issues] at the "What we do" section.

Comment: That's not *parallax* animation. That's a simple (and quite partial) **carousel** animation on :hover. There's a huge difference b/w the two.

Comment: Also, your intersectionObserver logic will not work if one views the app on a narrow viewport (not ever fully being in viewport - in other words, in where the slides occupy much more height than what triggers the observer callback)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan There *is* a parallax animation when viewed on mobile!

Comment: Oh, I've seen it now. Has some strange delay though. That's the problem you've mentioned  I guess

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan indeed, the "delay" is the keyword of the problem.

Comment: What if inside the JS part you set the transitionDuration to 0 ? I'm just guessing that instead of having a parallax 1:1 as you scroll - there's the transitionDuration messing around with the backgroundPosition for each item.

Comment: PS, make your life easier, instead of copy-pasting CSS (for pic1, 2, 3) use one single CSS rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every .pic1,2,3 's `transition-duration: 1s;` is interfering for what you see as the parallax for the `backgroundPosition`. Use only the duration for the properties that actually need one, otherwise the default is `all`. And you don't want that for the background's position. So use only the one for `filter`:

also, don't copy/paste code in CSS!
Use a single rule like

```
/* no need for .pic1, pic2, pic3 { as well */

.pic {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 32px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: white;
  transition: filter 1s; /* add transition only to filter! */
}

.pic1 {
  background-image: url(https://www.rgu.hu/CMF/jpg/laser-sci1.jpg);
}

.pic2 {
  background-image: url(https://www.rgu.hu/CMF/jpg/life-sci1.jpg);
}

.pic3 {
  background-image: url(https://www.rgu.hu/CMF/jpg/data-sci1.jpg);
}
```

and obviously add that class to all your HTML *pic* elements:

```html
class="pic pic1 parallax-image"
```